# XAMPP: Apache not starting

Tags: apache, xampp

[image: XAMPP Control Panel]

I had an older installation in folder C://xampp1 [ Windows 10 ] ; tried to uninstall that. I configured Apache to use port 8081.

But nothing happens. What to do?

EDIT: There are no apache error or access log files.

EDIT 9 nov.:[image: Wrong path? uninstall other service?]

I should disable or uninstall "the other service"; But How???

Comment: Any errors in the Apache log itself?

Comment: AFAIK, Apache uses port 80 by default which can be blocked by IIS or Skype. Also after configuring the apache to use 8081 port did you restart the xampp? Clicking on Netstat button can provide more info about ports being used.